# Is there a font that uses the same number of pixels per every horizontal letter?

Tags: java, fonts

I'm using buffered images and the (Graphics).drawLine and drawString methods to manually draw stuff to my game, and I implemented a high scores class that takes input through the keys the user types.  I manually created a blinking cursor using the drawLine method in Graphics, but each letter I notice doesn't necessarily line up with the prior letter.  The letter M, for example, is larger.  Is there a font that has the same number of pixels per letter horizontally?  Otherwise I'd have to account a different number of pixels per letter typed, which would take forever.

In other words, is there a font Java uses whose typed characters would align evenly like in accordance with an invisible grid behind it?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're looking for any fixed-width font.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Comment: [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html), [Measuring Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you!  Rather than putting the font type, there was an option to use Font.MONOSPACED as the font "type".  I'm sure there are font types that are like that as well but I like the look of the Font.MONOSPACED font, so that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) there's five fonts (font families actually) that all Java distributions must support:

```
Logical fonts are the five font families defined by the Java platform 
which must be supported by any Java runtime environment: Serif, SansSerif, 
Monospaced, Dialog, and DialogInput.
```

You want Monospaced.  You can ask for other fonts by name (such as LucidaConsole, which is a much nicer mononspaced font than the usual Courier), but if you ask for one of those five you're guaranteed to get a valid font back.

These work, for example (or at least return a font):

```
  Font f = Font.decode( "Lucida Console" );
  Font f2 = Font.decode( "Monospaced" );
```

If you want to see all the fonts on your system, you can use this:

```
  String[] fontList = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```